# Magento 2.4.5-p1 Sale order grid page very slowly

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I have a problem, the admin page loads very slowly. Especially the page that is a list such as the sale order grid.
Previously, I installed Magento 2.4.5-p1 in Ubuntu 22.10 and everything was fine. After that I move the Magento directory to ubuntu 22.04 and setup:upgrade in the old DB, and deploy it usually but in this new server web is slow, especially the admin page.
I tried checking php config, redis cache L2, and ES7 everything is the same.
I'm not sure if I'm still forgetting anything.

Comment: 1/ You should check Network tab to check the slowest calls. 2/ Checking server and Magento logs. 3/ If you have monitoring tools(New Relic, Blackfire), you should the check the reports from these tools. 4/ Check: Cache, Redis config.

Comment: Additional DB information request from slow server, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I am also currently using the same version but not facing any related issue but please check your any third party customization.